# How to redirect to the advertisement by clicking the url stored in the database?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I am developing a small app which stores the advertisement info. My model is like this:

```
class Advertising(models.Model):
  image_rect_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True,
                    validators=[validators.URLValidator])
  image_sqre_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True,
                    validators=[validators.URLValidator])
  clickthrough_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True,
                    validators=[validators.URLValidator])
  ads_copy = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
  vstart = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  vend = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  clicked = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
  viewed = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
```

Now when the user cilcks the clickthrough url he shuold be redirected to that advertisement.I need a basic idea how to implement this feature.The above model only stores the information of a particular advertisement and the number of times that add has been viewed and clicked will be the number of times the clickthrough url was clicked. Any ideas on implementing this feature?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this should do it

```
def view_for_redirect(request, id):
    redirect_url = Advertising.objects.get(id=id)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url.clickthrough_url)
```

I have omitted all of the checks you should do to see if it not None, just FYI.

Also, I really recommend [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) for these kinds of things, it's a quick google and it's always the first hit.